# past continuous or past perfect continuous in that case

Tags: past-tense

The prince **had been  searching** for ten hours when he was beginning to lose hope means the searching was finished that is  why he was beginning to lose hope

this is good  but can I replace by

"was searching" if at the time of writing he was still searching and did not give up searching even if he was also beginning to lose hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that "*the prince **was** searching....*" is past continuous tense and implies that the search is still going on from the perspective of the writer/speaker.

However, "*the prince **had been** searching for ten hours...*" (which is past perfect progressive tense) does not necessarily mean he has stopped searching either.

**Examples:**

> The prince had been searching for ten hours *when he gave up*.

This specifies that the search ended after ten hours, so the search *is* over.

> The prince had been searching for ten hours *when he began to lose hope*.

This only says that he began to lose hope, not that he stopped searching. It points to an event that occurred (his giving it hope) and it is *that* which occurred in the past.

Comment: was searching is it possible or not  and why not was beginning if the beginning was not over

Comment: @user5577 I do not understand your question.

Comment: @user5577, in this particular context, you can use *was searching*, but this doesn't mean that they're always interchangeable.

Comment: ok  in these context I can use was searching  but the emphasize is not on the duration but the present moment  and was beginning is it possible  (a beginning can last sometimes a long time)